# How do I get PHPUnit Polyfills set up for testing on a mac?

Tags: testing

Got a mac development machine with PHP installed via brew. I'm trying to get testing tools set up. I successfully set up test scaffolding with `wp` cli and managed to get `bin/install-wp-tests.sh` to do its thing.

But I get an error with `phpunit tests/test-sample.php`:

```
Error: The PHPUnit Polyfills library is a requirement for running the WP test suite.
If you are trying to run plugin/theme integration tests, make sure the PHPUnit Polyfills library (https://github.com/Yoast/PHPUnit-Polyfills) is available and either load the autoload file of this library in your own test bootstrap before calling the WP Core test bootstrap file; or set the absolute path to the PHPUnit Polyfills library in a "WP_TESTS_PHPUNIT_POLYFILLS_PATH" constant to allow the WP Core bootstrap to load the Polyfills.

If you are trying to run the WP Core tests, make sure to set the "WP_RUN_CORE_TESTS" constant to 1 and run `composer update -W` before running the tests.
Once the dependencies are installed, you can run the tests using the Composer-installed version of PHPUnit or using a PHPUnit phar file, but the dependencies do need to be installed whichever way the tests are run.
```

So I ran `composer require --dev yoast/phpunit-polyfills` and opened a new terminal window but still get the same error. Running `brew doctor` doesn't show anything related to php or composer.

I don't develop with PHP much so I'm at a loss as to what else to try.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I was reading from an outdated tutorial. Command for running tests is now:

`vendor/bin/phpunit <path_to_file>`

This command should be Run from root directory of wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it by adding the composer autoload to the top of my tests/bootstrap.php file...

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

After which I can run the normal `phpunit` command.